# A weak version of Shoenfield absoluteness theorem

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, constructibility

In my studies I found the following exercise

``Let $\phi\in \boldsymbol{\Delta}_{1}$ and $A,B\in L$, so
$$V\models \exists f\in {B}^{A}\,\forall x\in A\, \phi(x,f(x))$$
if and only if
$$L\models \exists f\in {B}^{A}\,\forall x\in A\, \phi(x,f(x))''$$

I am think if a analogue statement is tru for $\exists f\in {B}^{A}\,\forall x\in A\, \phi(x,f)$ with the same conditions.

Here, $L$ is the constructible universe, $V$ is the Von Neumann universe and $B^{A}$ the set of functions from $A$ in $B$.

Comment: $f$ is just left-most path of the tree generated by the formula and the parameters

Comment: can you indicate some reference? i really don't get it yet